# Marker label is never shown

Tags: google-maps

I am trying to add a marker with label specified in MarkerOptions, but i never see a label inside the icon. I know there is a class MarkerWithLabel, but for my purposes standard label will be enough, and this is how documentation describes it...

```
  vGeocoder.geocode( { 'address': vStart}, function(results, status) {
     if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        vStartMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: vMap,
            position: results[0].geometry.location,
            label: 'A',
            icon: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/yellow-dot.png"
        });

        vMap.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        vMap.setZoom(8);
     } else { alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status); }
  });
```

Comment: Please create http://jsfiddle.net/ or similar.

Comment: Your code works for me. The problem is your icon is overlapping the label, which is why you are not seeing it